# Please explain the Sequential Characterization of Limits more clearly.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

**Sequential Characterization of Limits** (SCL)

> Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$, let $I$ be an open interval which contains $a$, and let $f$ be a real function defined everywhere on $I$ except possibly at $a$. Then $$ L = \lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x) $$ exists if and only if $f(x_n) \to L$ as $n \to \infty$ for every sequence $x_n \in I \backslash \{a\}$ which converges to $a$ as $n \to \infty$.

What I know:

1. I know from learning calculus that a limit doesn't have to exist at a point, but haven't found a proof for that statement.
2. The formal definition of [Limit of a sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Formal_Definition) (barely).  I understand the concept, but still have trouble with properly writing the proofs.
3. I understand the first part of the statement of SCL; however, the last part confuses me. The domain of $f(x_n)$ is the sequence $x_n$, and $f(x_n) \to L$ means (?) that every point in the domain of $f(x)$ approaches L.  Is SCL only for functions that have a single point in it's range?

Comment: In 3. you are confusing domain and range. The $x_n$ are in the domain of $f$, $f(x_n)$ is in the range of $f$. Also $L$ is in the range of $f$. Also note that the definition only considers a limit at a specific point $a$. Hence, there is, in the case of existence of the limit, only one point in the range that really counts…

Comment: @Dirk let $x_n = 1,2,3$ for example then $f(1) \to L$, $f(2) \to L$ and $f(3) \to L$, that is what I am understanding, am I wrong?

Comment: $f(1)$ isn't going anywhere, it's the *sequence* $f(x_1),f(x_2),\dots$ that's approaching $L$, as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: As @GerryMyerson said, $x_n$ is a sequence. After close inspection of your post: You should have "…for every sequence $(x_n)$ in $I\setminus\{a\}$…". Clearer now?

Comment: @Dirk yes. I understand point 3, more clearly.